# Assigning HTMLImageElement to TexImageSource

Tags: typescript, webgl

I've got a variable that is of type TexImageSource and I'm trying to set a HTMLImageElement to it.

From what I understand a TexImageSource is:

```
type TexImageSource = ImageBitmap | ImageData | HTMLImageElement | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLVideoElement | OffscreenCanvas
```

Here is my image loading code:

```
return new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
    let image: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
    
    image.onload = () => { resolve(image); };
    image.onerror = error => { reject(error); };
    image.src = url;
});
```

```
const texture: TexImageSource = loadedImage;
```

The error that I get is:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'TexImageSource'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'OffscreenCanvas': height, width, convertToBlob, getContext, and 4 more.
```

I don't really understand why I'm getting this error, could anyone shed some light on the situation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a typescript expert but I think you need to declare the type of the `Promise`

```
function loadImage(url: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement> {
    return new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
        let image: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
        
        image.onload = () => { resolve(image); };
        image.onerror = error => { reject(error); };
        image.src = url;
    });
}

async function main() {
    const loadedImage = await loadImage('someImage.png');
    const texture: TexImageSource = loadedImage;
}
```

if I change

```
function loadImage(url: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement> {
```

to

```
function loadImage(url: string) {
```

then I get the error your question shows

You can also do this

```
function loadImage(url: string) {
    return new Promise<HTMLImageElement>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
```